# PHP - Find coordinates of group of pixel with similar color within a picture

Tags: php, image, imagick

I'm trying to get the coordinates of group of pixel with similar color in a picture using PHP. I think i have to use imagick, but after spending some time searching on the internet I cannot find exactly what I am looking for.

Let's say my base picture is entirely white with several colored shapes on it.
I want to get the coordinates of those shapes. It doesn't have to be exact coordinates, as long as the whole shape is in it.
Kind of like face recognition except much simpler.

Unfortunately I don't even know where to begin. I thought about comparing average pixel color every 5 pixels to map the whole picture, but it would be too time consuming.
There is probably already existing functions that does something like that, but I just can't find them.

[image: [I made a small drawing of what I am trying to do.]]

I have full control over the server(Linux CentOs) so I can install any required additional library.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'd say take a look at edge detection algorithms. Those are ready-to-use and already optimized. I never did that with imagick, though.

Comment: edge detection algorithms loop through all the pixels, too - here is a very simple example: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/10/19/image-edge-detection-algorithm-php-version/

Comment: Do you have a keyword/name of one of those algorithm to help me searching ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a most common GD library for PHP.

A function called **[imagecolorat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php)** returns the color at specified coordinates.

Yes, you need to compare every single pixel in the image or skip five pixels if that fits you needs.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't as simple as it may seem. I don't think there is a specific function to break an image up into regions/sprites like you're trying to do.

However it's not too difficult to do with the code and pseudo-code below:

```
//Load the image
$imagick = new Imagick(realpath("../images/image.png"));

//Get access to the actual pixels of an image
$imageIterator = $imagick->getPixelRegionIterator(0, 0, $imagick->getImageWidth(), $imagick->getImageHeight());

foreach ($imageIterator as $row => $pixels) { 
    foreach ($pixels as $column => $pixel) {  
            $color = $pixel->getColor();

            $spriteMapper->addPixel($color, $row, $column);
        }
    }
    $imageIterator->syncIterator(); /* Sync the iterator, this is important to do on each iteration */
}


class SpriteMapper {

    private $regions = array;

    function addPixel($color, $row, $column) {
        //If $color is background {
        //    return;
        //}  
        //
        //$found = false;
        //foreach ($regions as $region) {
        //    if ($row and $column are next to $region){
        //        make $region larger
        //        $found = true;
        //   }
        //}  
        //
        //if ($found === false) {
        //   $regions[] = new Region($row, $column);
        //}
    }
}
```

You'll still need to define exactly what happens when regions overlap, as well as defining exactly what overlapping means. In your example image the bottom sprites appear to be separate, but you've considered them to be overlapping for marking the region.

Yes, doing this will be relatively slow - but so long as you're not doing this for every web-request it shouldn't be a problem.

btw you may wish to search https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ for questions similar to this one, as this is something that

Comment: I decided to went for the "brute force" way and made a nice algorythm  that does what I wanted. Thanks for your help anyway, Ill be sure to check your link out to improve my code.

Comment: @Queno can you post your solution?